# Set different data/folders for different domains on apache

Tags: apache, ftp, system-administration, ubuntu-server

So I have Ubuntu 16 installed with LAMP and couple of other things on it (like FTP server...).

IP of my VPS is 1.2.3.4.

I have 2 domains, example.com and mydomain.com - both of these domains have their A record pointed at 1.2.3.4

If I access 1.2.3.4 and example.com and mydomain.com in my browser, all those three are showing the SAME data, specifically the contents of `/var/www/html` - if I change content of this directory it affects example.com and mydomain.com and the 1.2.3.4.

Now how can I set additional folders for domains to read from? I want different data on example.com and on mydomain.com - I want to make them read from different folder on server. How can i setup this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is technically defined as setting virtual hosts which could be set using the following steps:

Under your Apache configurations directory, usually at **/etc/apache2/**, you will find a directory named **sites-enabled**.

For each of your domains, you will need to configure a special configuration file in order to point them to the right direction. The name of the file is typically your-domain.conf.

Here's an example of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port
    # that the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName your_domain
    ServerAlias www.your_domain
    ServerAdmin webmaster@your_domain
    DocumentRoot website_directory

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Directory website_directory>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After saving the file you will need to restart the Apache server
`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Repeat the above steps for each of your domains.
If everything goes right, your site will show when you access your domain.